# jQuery pageX/pageY returning different values on different devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm using the following code which I've collected from various sources to try to work out the coordinates of an image on a click:

```
var naturalWidth = 690;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

var img = $('.imageToWin');
ratio = naturalWidth / img.width();
x = parseInt((event.pageX - img.offset().left) * ratio);
y = parseInt((event.pageY - img.offset().top) * ratio);
```

However the actual coordinates change when the same point is clicked on different devices (e.g. laptops, tablets, phones etc...). I did read somewhere about changing it to use a percentage however when I tried dividing by image height/width it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the purpose of this work ?

Comment: I need to work out the exact coordinate of the point a user clicks/taps on an image which should be the same across all devices.

Comment: Your finger is larger than a mouse pointer, so it may connect with another (x,y) coordinate. Are the coordinates returned drastically different, or just slightly off?

Comment: by saying exactly the same it won't work unless the size of the image is the same in all the devices are you sure it is?

Comment: @J.Titus Yes they are around 15 off on my iPad and can be upto 50 off on laptops.

Comment: @YehiaAwad I have set the min/max width and height of the css class of the image to the size it is served in. Wordpress does that so I have set its custom size there too.

Comment: Both aren't completely unreasonable considering (I'm assuming) all of the devices you're using have a different pixel density. Do you define a `viewport` meta tag on your page for mobile devices to take advantage of?

Comment: @J.Titus Its not awful, but due to the results being used for a game it needs to be accurate and fair. I don't think I have added a viewpoint no, where is the best place to add this? Thanks!

Comment: Always in the `<head>` section of the page.

Comment: @J.Titus No luck with adding the viewport tag, the results on my iPad are 153 out. Are there any other ways you could suggest I do it? Maybe i need to use something other than jQuery?

Comment: Im considering leaving tablet/phone for now and just getting desktop working and accurate. Having tried it on two macbook pro's today virtually identical apart from one having retina and the coordinates were 63 out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did figure this out in the end on my own! I decided to make use of an iframe to bring the image into the page and handle the positioning on the new page to work out where the coordinates would be via jQuery. This works correctly on tablets, phones, laptops and desktops alike.